# How to select rows based on exact count of array elements in a different column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a dataframe like this, where `B_C` is concat of col `B` and col `C`, and column `selected_B_C` is an array formed by picking a few `B_C` col from within the group.

```
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|A          |grp_count_A|B       |C       |B_C              |D       |selected_B_C                          |
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|1          |6          |30261.41|20091201|30261.41_20091201|99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|
|1          |6          |30261.41|20081201|30261.41_20081201|99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|
|1          |6          |39879.85|20080601|39879.85_20080601|99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|
|1          |6          |69804.42|20080117|69804.42_20080117|99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|
|1          |6          |99950.3 |20090301|99950.3_20090301 |99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|
|1          |6          |99999.23|20080118|99999.23_20080118|99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|
|2          |4          |76498.0 |20150501|76498.0_20150501 |183600.0|[[76498.0_20150501, 76498.0_20150501]]|
|2          |4          |76498.0 |20150501|76498.0_20150501 |183600.0|[[76498.0_20150501, 76498.0_20150501]]|
|2          |4          |76498.0 |20150501|76498.0_20150501 |183600.0|[[76498.0_20150501, 76498.0_20150501]]|
|2          |4          |351378.0|20180620|351378.0_20180620|183600.0|[[76498.0_20150501, 76498.0_20150501]]|
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
```

I want to append a column `selected` where it takes a value `1`, if for a row, col `B_C` is found in col`selected_B_C`, otherwise `0`, so the final dataframe looks like this.

```
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------+
|A          |grp_count_A|B       |C       |B_C              |D       |selected_B_C                          |selected|
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------+
|1          |6          |30261.41|20081201|30261.41_20081201|99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|0       |
|1          |6          |30261.41|20091201|30261.41_20091201|99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|1       |
|1          |6          |39879.85|20080601|39879.85_20080601|99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|1       |
|1          |6          |69804.42|20080117|69804.42_20080117|99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|0       |
|1          |6          |99950.3 |20090301|99950.3_20090301 |99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|0       |
|1          |6          |99999.23|20080118|99999.23_20080118|99945.83|[30261.41_20091201, 39879.85_20080601]|0       |
|2          |4          |76498.0 |20150501|76498.0_20150501 |183600.0|[[76498.0_20150501, 76498.0_20150501]]|1       |
|2          |4          |76498.0 |20150501|76498.0_20150501 |183600.0|[[76498.0_20150501, 76498.0_20150501]]|1       |
|2          |4          |76498.0 |20150501|76498.0_20150501 |183600.0|[[76498.0_20150501, 76498.0_20150501]]|0       |
|2          |4          |351378.0|20180620|351378.0_20180620|183600.0|[[76498.0_20150501, 76498.0_20150501]]|0       |
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

The tricky part for col `selected` is that I only want the exact number of occurrences of a value in `selected_B_C` to have value `1` for selected

- For example in group `2`, even though there are 3 records with value of `76498.0_20150501` for col `B_C`, I want only two records from group `2` whose value is `76498.0_20150501` to have value of `1` for `selected`, as `selected_B_C` for group `2` has exactly 2 elements with value `76498.0_20150501` in col `selected_B_C`

Comment: `when(col("B_C").isin(flatten(col("selected_B_C")), 1).otherwise(0)` I have not tested.

Comment: Thanks @Lamanus this would assign a value of `1` for the 9th record, but I want the value for 9th record to be `0`, since `selected_B_C` array for group `2` has only two `76498.0_20150501` elements

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of group 2. Ah, only the first two of them to make selected!

Comment: By group 2, I refer to group of records where value for column `A` is  `2`